# VBS zipping script

Tags: vbscript, zip

I found (apparently working for everybody) script which only needs to be modified (paths):

```
Sub NewZip(pathToZipFile)
  'WScript.Echo "Newing up a zip file (" & pathToZipFile & ") "

  Dim fso
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim file
  Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(pathToZipFile)

  file.Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)

  file.Close
  Set fso = Nothing
  Set file = Nothing

  WScript.Sleep 500
End Sub

Sub CreateZip(pathToZipFile, dirToZip)
  'WScript.Echo "Creating zip  (" & pathToZipFile & ") from (" & dirToZip & ")"

  Dim fso
  Set fso= Wscript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  pathToZipFile = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(pathToZipFile)
  dirToZip = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(dirToZip)

  If fso.FileExists(pathToZipFile) Then
    'WScript.Echo "That zip file already exists - deleting it."
    fso.DeleteFile pathToZipFile
  End If

  If Not fso.FolderExists(dirToZip) Then
    'WScript.Echo "The directory to zip does not exist."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  NewZip pathToZipFile

  dim sa
  set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

  Dim zip
  Set zip = sa.NameSpace(pathToZipFile)

  'WScript.Echo "opening dir  (" & dirToZip & ")"

  Dim d
  Set d = sa.NameSpace(dirToZip)

  ' Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787866(VS.85).aspx
  ' for more information about the CopyHere function.
  zip.CopyHere d.items, 4

  Do Until d.Items.Count <= zip.Items.Count
    Wscript.Sleep(200)
  Loop
End Sub
```

Can anybody give example how this script should look like with 
real paths? I'm trying but it's not working for me.

Comment: Define "not working". How are you calling the procedures (exactly), and what result do you get?

Answer (score 1):

This script consists solely of two subroutines and thus will never execute anything.

Add the following line to the bottom of the file and it should work (given that the code in the subs is sound, I have not tested):

```
CreateZip "c:\output\test.zip" "c:\input\"
```

This will do the following, in order:

1. Check to see if the output file exists. If it does, it will delete it.
2. Check to see if the input folder exists, if it does not, the script will exit.
3. Call the `NewZip` sub which just creates an "empty" .zip file.
4. Copy files to the zip file.
5. Pause for a while, probably to ensure you don't try to access the ZIP before it's done copying.

The contents of the `input` folder will now be in the zip file in the `output` folder.